# Regmatches over two lists in R

Tags: r, matching, fuzzy-search

I figured out the positions of approximate machtes in the `targetframe` with the help of the `word.library` with the following code:

```
tragetframe <- data.frame(words= c("Important Words",
                                   "I would also Importante worde of thes substring",
                                   "No mention of this crazy sayingsys"))

word.library <- data.frame(mainword = c("important word",
                                        "crazy sayings"),
                           keyID =c("2000", "3000"))

##find position
find <- function(word.library, tragetframe) {
  aregexec(word.library, tragetframe, max.distance = 0.1)
}

positions <- lapply(word.library[,1], find, tragetframe[,1])
```

Afterwards I want to extract the matched substrings, but it does not work:

```
extract <- function(tragetframe, positions ) {
  regmatches(tragetframe, positions)
}
extracted_machtes <- lapply(tragetframe[,1], extract, positions)
```

Hope someone can help me finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapply(regmatches, tragetframe, positions)
     words             <NA>           
[1,] "Important Word"  Character,0    
[2,] "Importante word" Character,0    
[3,] Character,0       "crazy sayings"
```

`?mapply` runs the function inputted with the first element of the other objects, then the second of each and so on.